# Using d3-collection nest how to group data by continuous date

Tags: javascript, d3.js, group-by

I have a JSON Array that I need to group by one of the fields. The field is a timestamp but I need to group by date ONLY. The data looks something like this:

```
[
  {
    "id":1,
    "title":"blah blah",
    "startTime":"2018-07-27T19:03:44.965Z"
  },
  {
    "id":2,
    "title":"blah blah",
    "startTime":"2018-07-25T19:03:44.965Z"
  }
]
```

I also needed the grouped data to contain a continuous date. For example there should be one entry for `2018-07-26`.

I can manually do all of that using ES6. But, I'm wondering if I can achieve the same using d3-collection's `nest` function. Using the `nest` function, I'm able to group the data by date, but I'm not sure how to get the continuous date series.

Comment: Construct a list of dates that are found in the array, sort the list of dates, convert the dates to UTC-milliseconds and compare if they are the right amount of milliseconds apart, if not add the missing dates by converting the milliseconds back to a `new Date(millisecondUTC)`

Comment: As I mentioned, I can do all of that myself. Using `d3.nest()` and `Moment` library I can group the data by just date also. I'm asking how do I add the missing dates in to the array while grouping the data by date.

Comment: The grouping operation does not take the whole dataset into account it is just a single loop that appends array elements in a dictionary by key. You need a pre or post operation to fix your dataset.